# What is an "Apothecary" in Heroville?

Tags: heroville

So I was playing heroville and I came across a hero and I could assign his take to apothecary, what does this do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Town" tab, you will see a table in the bottom right that has a list of jobs and descriptions for each.  For Apothecary, it says this:

> Apothecary | An Apothecary will make potions.

Here is a screenshot of part of the table:

[image: Job]

Comment: so how do potions work?

Comment: @Chantola Potions are automatically used by the hero and will restore 20% of their HP.  However, the description for it says: *the bottles are too fragile to take into dungeons*

Comment: Ok, so I can make potions so they will steal from me and instantly heal themselves. Got it. So do they work in dungeons?

Comment: @Chantola Potions cannot be used in dungeons, they will be purchased when the hero returns home, if needed.